# calling main method inside main in java

Tags: java, methods, program-entry-point

Can we call main method inside main?

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    main({"a","b","c"});
}
```

Tried to google.Can't find the link.
Sorry if the question is trivial

Comment: Don't google it, just try it and see what happens. What do you think will happen?

Comment: Resulting in compliation error

Comment: You should look up array initialization expressions.

Comment: Why is this question -3 , it's reasonable

Comment: @Coffee: probably because there is zero effort put into it. Fixing the syntax and executing it would have answered it way faster.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can but using the correct format

```
main(new String[] {"a","b","c"});
```

should give StackOverFlowError (not tested)

Comment: It's StackOverFlowError

Answer (score 4):

You will get [`StackOverFlowError`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StackOverflowError.html). If you call endless recursive calls/deep function recursions.

> Thrown when a stack overflow occurs because an application recurses
>   too deeply.

You need to pass String array like

```
main(new String[] {"a","b","c"});
```

Answer (score 4):

You can. And it is very much legal.
Also, it doesn't necessarily give a StackOverFlowError:

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    int randomNum = (int)(Math.random()*10);

    if(randomNum >= 8)
    System.exit(0);

    System.out.print("Heyhey!");
    main(new String[]{"Anakin", "Ahsoka", "Obi-Wan"});

}
```

Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

Kugathasan is right.

Yes it does give StackOverflow Exception. I tested it right now in Eclipse.

```
class CallingMain
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
         main(new String[] {"a","b","c"});
    }
}
```

I have one suggestion, I think the best way to eliminate the confusion is to try coding and running it. Helps with lots of doubts.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply pass the argument like `main(new String[1])` - this line will call main method of your program. But if you pass "`new String[-1]`" this will give NegativeArraySizeException. Here I'mm giving an example of Nested Inner Class where I am calling the Main method:

```
class Outer 
{
    static class NestedInner
    {

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
            System.out.println("inside main method of Nested class");

        }//inner main
    }//NestedInner
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {

        NestedInner.main(new String[1] );//**calling of Main method**
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }//outer main
}//Outer
```

Output:-
inside main method of Nested class

Hello World!

Comment: No, you cannot! Whereas the compiler won't complain, the recursion you create would exhaust the stack quite fast.

Comment: this code is not for recursion, this is simple code for calling How to call Main method

Comment: What is it when you call main from main?