# I need some help getting my program to repeat

Tags: java, loops, netbeans

I developed a program that checks if a string entered by a user is a palindrome or not. That part works fine but I I'd like the program to start again if the user wants to enter another string. I have looked on different forums and tried different loops but I can't get the program to repeat properly. I currently have a do statement and I think the problem is to do with calling `main()` as it is flagged in `netbeans`. I don't know why though. Any help or a nudge in the right direction would be appreciated.

```
/*
 * This program checks to see if the user input is a palindrome.
 * white space and non alphanumeric characters will be ignored.
 */
package firstsubroutines;

/**
 *
 * @author anonymous
 */

public class FirstSubroutines {

    static String str; // global variable
    static String reversed; // global variable

/*
 * The subroutine strp accepts a string as an argument
 * and returns a string stripped of spaces and 
 * non alphanumeric characters
 */    
    static String strip(String str){
        str = str.replaceAll("[^a-zA-Z0-9]", "");
        str = str.toLowerCase();
        System.out.println("Stripped: " + str);
        return str;
    } // end of subroutine stripped

/*
 * The subroutine reverse accepts a string as an argument
 * and returns a string in reverse order
 */
    static String reverse(String str){
        int i;
        reversed = "";
        for (i = str.length() - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            reversed = reversed + str.charAt(i);
        }
        System.out.println("Reversed: " + reversed);
        return reversed;
    } // end of subroutine reversed

/*
 * This is the main progam where the subroutines
 * will be called
 */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String userInput; // The input by the user.

        System.out.println("This program checks to see if the user's input is a palindrome.");
        System.out.println("White space and non alphanumeric characters will be ignored.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Please enter a string: ");
        userInput = TextIO.getln(); // assigns the user input to a variable

        // subroutine strip is called and an the value of 
        // the variable userInput is passed
        str = strip(userInput);

       // subroutine reverse is called and an the value of 
       // the variable str is passed
       String rev = reverse(str);

       // compares the two objects
       if ( str.equals(rev) ) {
            System.out.println("This IS a palindrome");
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("This NOT a palindrome");
        } // end of if statement


        boolean toContinue;  // True if user wants to play again.
        do {
            main();
            System.out.print("Do you want enter another string?: ");
            toContinue = TextIO.getlnBoolean();
            } while (toContinue == true);

    } // end main

} // end class
```

Comment: Are you actually calling the public static void main(String[] args) method in your loop ?

Comment: Yes. Is that not what I should be doing?

Comment: You should not do that. The main method should not be called :) see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21992659/calling-main-method-inside-main-in-java. I'll explain you how to do in an another way. @Berger did answer what I was thinking

Comment: Thanks @Stilleur I'll read the stack overflow answer you mentioned.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Separate your input treatment logic to another method :

```
private static void processString(){

        String userInput; // The input by the user.

        System.out.println("This program checks to see if the user's input is a palindrome.");
        System.out.println("White space and non alphanumeric characters will be ignored.");
        System.out.println();
        System.out.print("Please enter a string: ");
        userInput = TextIO.getln(); // assigns the user input to a variable

        // subroutine strip is called and an the value of 
        // the variable userInput is passed
        str = strip(userInput);

       // subroutine reverse is called and an the value of 
       // the variable str is passed
       String rev = reverse(str);

       // compares the two objects
       if ( str.equals(rev) ) {
            System.out.println("This IS a palindrome");
        } 
        else {
            System.out.println("This NOT a palindrome");
        } // end of if statement


}
```

Then just call it from `main` in a loop :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

        boolean toContinue = false;  // True if user wants to play again.
        do {
            processString();
            System.out.print("Do you want enter another string?: ");
            toContinue = TextIO.getlnBoolean();
            } 
       while (toContinue == true);
}
```

Comment: Thanks that worked great and I think I have a better understanding of why mine didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`Scanner`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html) class:

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

while (sc.hasNext()) {
    String input = sc.next();
    // do something with input
}
```